linear gradient backround image not showing
Although, I inserted the image it is not showing at all.Also when I use the browser inspect tool it shows that the image is there but the browser not showing.
background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #0783fe, #7ed56f), url(../img/hero.jpg);


Please add enough (relevant) code inside your question to create [mre]

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

There are several methods or ways that you can achieve the output I will list them one by one
Using background blend mode property
background-blend-mode: lighten;

You can change the values as per the design you are looking for
Using rgba values instead of HEX values to define colors of gradient
background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(7, 131, 254, 0.5),rgba(126, 213, 111, 0.5)), url(./image.png);

The a value is for alpha or opacity the range is between 0 to 1
You can add additional values to HEX code
background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #0783fe5b, #7ed56f5b), url("./CodeChefBadge.png");

Same as the rgba "5b" represents the opacity of the color
Place image first
background-image: url("./CodeChefBadge.png"),linear-gradient(to right bottom, #0783fe, #7ed56f);

The problem is arising in the first place is due to that the linear gradient is applied over the image. And because you are not specifying the opacity or intensity of the colors the image is hidden. This are some of the methods you can try and check what works our for you the best. Hope the answer is helpfull.
